# Truncation error in approximation of $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2x}$

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a function $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2x}$. In order to avoid loss of significance when calculating values of this function near $x=0$, I represent $e^x$ as Taylor series. The truncation error of $e^x$ is $\frac{x^5}{5!}*e^x$ (If i use 4 members of Taylor series for the approximation). But this is the error only for $e^x$, not for the whole function. How to compute truncation error for $\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2x}$ when $e^x$ is computed using Taylor series approximation?

This question continues this series here: [Truncation error in approximation of $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431180/truncation-error-in-approximation-of-fracex-1x) because I could not do the same manipulations with this formula as with the previous answer

Comment: $$\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x} = x + \dfrac16x^3 + \dfrac1{120}x^5 + \cdots = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$$

Comment: How did you come up with this result? I mean the original formula can be written ofc as $(e^{2x} - 1)/{e^x2x}$ but then...how did you expand it like that?

Comment: Correction: $$\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x} = 1 + \dfrac16x^2 + \dfrac1{120}x^4 + \cdots = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{(2n+1)!} x^{2n}$$ obtained by expanding $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ separately and then using term-by-term subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use up to the $x^4$ term,

Hint:

$$e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\frac1{24}x^4\pm\frac1{120}x^5e^{|x|}$$

where $\pm$ denotes maximum error. By setting $x\mapsto-x$, we get

$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac12x^2-\frac16x^3+\frac1{24}x^4\pm\frac1{120}x^5e^{|x|}$$

What do you get when you subtract these and divide by $2x$?

Comment: Yep, I got the reasoning behind this, due to Kenny Lau's comment. Only 1 thing after your comment in the linked question - this problem is the same that you answered about $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ - what about the error term? should it be with x^4, or how to properly assess the error term?

Comment: @John To what terms are you expanding $e^x$?

Comment: Note that the exact remainder is generally given by:$$e^x-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^1(1-t)^ne^{xt}~\mathrm dt$$Upon which we usually simplify the integral:$$\left|\int_0^1(1-t)^ne^{xt}~\mathrm dt\right|\le e^{|x|}$$

Comment: I expand $e^x$ to four terms (1st term is 1), 5th term should be an error

Comment: I think I don't need the precise remainder as it seems like integral is hard to compute and it is sure not what is required from me. The whole task is - examine function (I gave) in the range of values 10^-7 to 10^-9, but due to loss of significance you are not allowed to use direct computation, so expand each $e^x$ term into Taylor with 4 members, -> and then suddenly the exercise says - now the error term is the fifth member of Taylor series. I do not think this is right for the whole formula (and we take the endpoint as just $x$, so no need for the integral - we take upper bound)

Comment: @John Well, you can probably figure out how to change my answer to four terms (just remove the last term pretty much)

Comment: Usually, when texts say "now the error term is the fifth member of Taylor series" they usually mean to use the [Lagrange Remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html), which is close, but not quite, to the fifth term in the expansion. Here, it says that$$e^x-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^\xi$$for some $|\xi|<x$. (The exact value of $\xi$ is not important, as you can, for your range, use $e^\xi<e^1<3$)

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}=\dfrac{\sinh (x)}{x}= 1+\dfrac{x^2}{6}+\dfrac{x^4}{120}+\dfrac{x^6}{5040}+\dfrac{x^8}{362880}+O(x^9)$

The series is
$$\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 n}}{(2 n+1)!}$$